# Where does this expectation formula come from?

Tags: probability-theory

I seem to recall seeing, for a positive random variable X,

$$E[X] = \int P[X \geq x] dx$$

from some proof somewhere, but now a paper referenced the formula without reference and I can't find anything about it. Where does it come from?

Comment: just use Fubini theorem: integrate the characteristic function of $X\geq x$ over $\Omega\times \mathbb R$ ($\Omega$ your probability space)

Comment: Here's one reference, [page 3, item 3](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic107863.files/7-ContinuousRV.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-negative random variable $X$ we have
$$
\int_{0}^\infty P[X\ge x]\,dx=\int_{0}^\infty\int_{x}^\infty f(y)\,dy\,dx=\int_{0}^\infty\int_{0}^y f(y)\,dx\,dy\\
=\int_{0}^\infty yf(y)dy=E[X]
$$
Similar manipulations show for any random variable $X$ the following holds
$$
E[X]=\int_0^\infty P[X>x]dx-\int_0^\infty P[X<-x]dx
$$